# Defining a variable "C programming"

Tags: c

This is my program below to calculate the mpg value, then convert it 
to liter-per-100-km value.
My question is why when I define the mpg variable as you see in comment number 1 my program outputs wrong values but when I define it as you see on comment number 2, the program outputs correct values?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define GAL_TO_LIT 3.785
#define MILE_TO_KM 1.609

int main()
{
    float miles;
    float gallons;
    float mpg;              //1 float mpg = miles / gallons;

    printf("Enter the number of miles traveled: ");
    scanf("%f", &miles);
    printf("Enter the number of gallons gasoline consumed: ");
    scanf("%f", &gallons);

    mpg = miles / gallons;  //2 

    printf("The miles-per-gallon value is: %.1f\n", mpg);
    printf("The liters-per-100-km value is: %.1f\n",
    100. / mpg * GAL_TO_LIT / MILE_TO_KM);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For some specified input, what is the actual *and* expected output?

Answer (score 1):

When program execution reaches the line with the first comment, `miles` and `gallons` have indeterminate values since they have not been initializes nor assigned to. Accessing those values is undefined behaviour.

In the line with your 2nd comment `miles` and `gallons` have already got values by `scanf()` and everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Actual values of `miles` and `gallons` have been assigned once you use `scanf`. Before that when the variable is initialized both variables are having some random "garbage" value.

I can see you have just started programming and my only advice will be to always perform the operations on variable once the proper value has been assigned to them (like in comment 2).